# Strapi LEFT JOIN two Tables

Tags: api, rest, strapi

It's my first experience with Strapi. I'm Flutter developer.
I want to make API for my App. I need join two tables in one API request.
I have table1 and table2 witch has link with users.

It should works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userId = myId) AS tab2 On table1.id = tab2.id;
```

Is there already method in Strapi (4.3.8) or I need to make this myself?

I know about relationship. I can make this request:

```
/api/words?populate=user_words
```

But I need to select user_words only for my user, not all users as it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine it with the `filters` param, e.g:

`/api/words?populate=user_words&filters[user_id][$eq]=1234`

More on that: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/filters-locale-publication#filtering.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this solution. But I dot't think it's safe?! Anyone can get information about other users. I thought there was method to get data only from authorized users.

Comment: There's a separate official plugin that allows you to configure the protection levels: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/users-permissions